# call to method with button that another method send to a div

Tags: javascript

i have some JavaScript object like this:

```
<div id='demo'>demo</div>

function obj() {
     this.a = function () {
          $('#demo').html("<a href='javascript: this.b();'>button</a>");     // here is the problem
     }

     this.b = function () {
          alert('bbbbbbbb');
     }
}
```

i have some method, that send some button to a div. i want to act another method (`this.b()`) with this button.

when i click on the button, its not work, and i understand why its not work.

there is any way to make this button work? (to call to `this.b()` method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind the function as the `click` handler.

```
this.a = function () {
    $('<a/>').text('button').appendTo($('#demo').empty()).on('click', this.b);
}
```

Note that `this` keyword in the context of the `b` method refers to the clicked element, if it should refer to the object's instance, you can either use `Function.prototype.bind` or `jQuery.proxy` method for setting the desired value.

```
this.a = function () {
    $('<a/>', {
       text: 'button',
       click: this.b.bind(this) // calls the `on` method behind the scenes
    }).appendTo($('#demo').empty());
};
this.b = function(event) {
    // when the `b` method is called as click handler 
    // `this` refers to the current instance  
    var clickedElement = event.currentTarget;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly identical since you're appending rather than replacing the existing content, but the general idea of using `.on()` is solid. No idea why you were downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

---

Alternatively to the full jQuery solution by [`Vohuman`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803336/call-to-method-with-button-that-another-method-send-to-a-div/26803457#26803457), you can also alter your existing code as follows:

---

The problem is possibly in the fact that you have: `<a href='javascript: this.b();'>button</a>`

Instead, you could do:

> `<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='new myFunction().b()'>button</a>`

So for example, you could do:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    new myFunction().a();
});

function myFunction() {
    this.a = function () {
        $('#demo').html("<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='new myFunction().b()'>button</a>");
    }
    this.b = function () {
        alert('bbbbbbbb');
    }
}
```

Which works like you wanted.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wf51msa1/)